# Nonetype object has no attribute 'items' when looping through a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one represents a player inventory and the other represents a dragon inventory. I'm trying to take the two dictionaries and combine them. Then display those two dictionaries as the player's new inventory. I have added my code below and I keep getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/DakotaDickey/Documents/Python Projects /Examples/FantasyGameAddToInventory.py", line 38, in <module>
    displayInventory(inv)
  File "/Users/DakotaDickey/Documents/Python Projects /Examples/FantasyGameAddToInventory.py", line 27, in displayInventory
    for k, v  in inventory.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

my code:

```
#FantasyGameAddToInventory


def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    addedItemsdict = {} 
    for item in addedItems:
        x = addedItems.count(item)
        if item not in addedItemsdict:
            addedItemsdict[item] = 1
        else:
            addedItemsdict[item] = x

    for k, v in addedItemsdict.items():
        if k in inventory:
            x = inventory[k]
            inventory[k] = v + x
        else:
            inventory[k] = v
    inv = inventory           
    print(inv)

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    item_total = 0

    for k, v  in inventory.items():
        print(k,v)
        item_total = item_total + v



    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

inv = {'gold coin' : 42 , 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger' , 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

The output Im trying to produce is as follows. 
Inventory:

45 gold coin

1 rope

1 ruby

1 dagger

Total number of items: 48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `addToInventory()` returns `None`, which you assign to `inv`:

```
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Now `inv` is set to `None` and you pass that to `displayInventory()`.

Add `return inv` at the end of `addToInventory()`.

Remember, printing is not the same thing as returning; printing writes data to your terminal, the caller of a function doesn't receive that data.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could zip the two dictionaries together:

```
inv = zip(inventory, dragonLoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much shorter way to write the addToInventory(inventory, addedItems) function:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for k in addedItems:
        if k not in inventory:
            inventory.setdefault(k, 1)
        else:
            inventory[k] += 1
    return inventory
```

Comment: Why use `setdefault` here? You're already checking if the key is in the dictionary, and don't use the return value.